# Javascript: getting rid of nested loop

Tags: javascript

It's been a while since I wrote any Javascript. Is there a more elegant way to do this. Specifically want to get rid of the second loop:

```
<script>

var number = 0;
for (var i=1; i<11; i++) {
    for (var x=1; x<11; x++) { 

        if (i==1) { 
            number = x;
        } else { 
            number = Math.pow(i, x);
        }

        document.write(number + " ");

        if (x == 10) { 
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please put down the problem statement here. By the solution, it is really difficult to tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are generating a table. Typically this is going to need 2 nested loops - one for rows, the second for columns.

Comment: The problem is to loop from 1-10 and then on separate lines print out 1-10, 1-10 to the power of 2, 1-10 to the power of 3, etc.

Comment: That's not what you're currently printing (the arguments for `Math.pow()` are the wrong way round). Once you've swapped the arguments, you can remove the entire `if` clause and just print `Math.pow(x, i)`.

Comment: it's not the place for that question, use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with 2 loops but i would change one if statement and move it after the 2nd loop and avoid `document.write` and insert it all at once to reduce the number of time you change the DOM

```js
let result = ''

for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let x = 1; x < 11; x++)
        result += (i==1 ? x : Math.pow(i, x)) + ' '
    result += '<br>'
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', result)
```

**Edit** If you really don't want the 2nd loop:

```js
let result = ''

// you must swap the condition to check for x instead of i
for (let i = 1, x = 1; x < 11; i++) {
    result += (x==1 ? i : Math.pow(x, i)) + ' '

    // and reset i and increase x yourself
    if (i == 10) {
        i = 0
        x++
        result += '<br>'
    }
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', result)
```

**Edit2** just for the fun: No for loops.
Just a recursive function :P

```js
function build(i = 1, x = 1, res = '') {
    res += (x == 1 ? i : Math.pow(x, i)) + ' '
    i == 10 ? (x++, i=1, res += '<br>') : i++
    return x == 11 ? res : build(i, x, res)
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', build())
```

Comment: Thnaks. Doesn't save on complexity but it is cleaner. This would be O(n2) right?

Comment: Yep, figured if you really don't want that 2nd loop i made another solution for you

Comment: Added another with no for loops just for the sake of it, but nothing beats the first as more readable

Comment: Love the recursive function

Answer (score 0):

In terms of 'elegancy', I'd go for [`for... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops or [`map function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). That doesn't solve  your nested loop though.

On a side note, nested loops are not necessarily bad. If that's the correct way to implement the specific algorithm, then that's how it is.

Comment: If this was Swift I could do for i in 1...10, does Javascript support that? (It's been a while since I've looked at Javascript)

Comment: @PruitIgoe In JS you can do `for (let i in [1, 2, 3]) { // do stuff }`, this loop over the index of each item. You can instead go for `for...of` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Using Math.pow() is un-necessary overhead. Nested loops are not necessarily bad.

```
var number = 0;
for (var i=1; i<11; i++) {
    document.write(i + " ");
    number = i;
    for (var x=2; x<11; x++) {
        number = (i == 1) ? x : number * i;
        document.write(number + " ");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way with only one loop:

```
[...Array(100)].map((_,i) => {
    document.write(((i>9)?Math.pow(Math.floor((i+10)/10),(i%10)+1):i+1) + ' ' + ((i%10==9)?'<br>':''));
});
```

Comment: that's nice, but the complexity is still there, even if its hidden in map. Was hoping to get rid of the nested loop but looks like it remains.

Comment: @PruitIgoe you can't remove the complexity (it's never going to stop being a 2d array). But you can make it more mysterious :).

Comment: @PruitIgoe I've edited my answer to minimise readability by making it a one-liner with only one loop

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it with **1 loop only**, tho not as clean:

```js
var number = 0;
var x = 1;
var calc = 0;
var calcx = 1;
var increment = false;

for (var i=1; i<101; i++) {
      increment = false;
      calc = i % 10;
      if(calc == 0){
       calc = 10;
        increment = true;
      }
      if (calcx==1) { 
        number = calc;
      } else { 
        number = Math.pow(calcx, calc);
        console.log(calcx+" "+calc);
      }
      document.write(number + " ");
      if (i % 10 == 0) { 
     document.write("<br>");
      }
      if(increment){
     calcx++;
      }
}
```

Comment: You could do it with no loops, by just writing the required output to the dom

Comment: @chrisLear or with a recursive function

Comment: @Endless nice idea

Comment: @ChrisLear I don't get your comment. The OP posted code with 2 loops and asked for the same output to be written without nested loop and "Specifically want to get rid of the second loop:" My answer addresses the question directly, I just didn't do it before Endless' more elegant and efficient way.

Comment: @AmmoPT sorry. I didn't mean to offend. I was being facetious. There's nothing wrong with your answer. I'm actually trying to write a version that is more or less based on yours, because it's a fun challenge.

Comment: I'm sorry too if I came across as an offended fragile flower. No harm no foul. And I learned the meaning of the word "facetious". Have a good one @ChrisLear